# How do i get screen time of other applications in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to reach screen time of every application that's working on android system. For example, there are 3 hours of facebook working time but 1.2 hours of screen time. How can i get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android.app.usage
```

**UsageStats**

```
public final class UsageStats 
extends Object implements Parcelable

java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.app.usage.UsageStats
```

What you need I think is

```
getFirstTimeStamp
```

Get the beginning of the time range this [UsageStats](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStats#getFirstTimeStamp()) represents, measured in milliseconds since the epoch.
and `getLastTimeStamp`

Get the end of the time range this `UsageStats` represents, measured in milliseconds since the epoch.

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStats)

Comment: Thanks for referance.
In the referance "long getTotalTimeInForeground ()" is solved my problem.

Comment: did it help?I cant see anywhere the screen time,that you want but where do you see this in your mobile?